# Installing chain link fence gate, need advice on terminating the existing fence top rail

Tags: fence

I'm installing a fence gate in a chain link fence (*with neighbor's permission, of course*) I would like to use the existing fence post as the terminator post for that chunk of fence, rather than replacing it.

I have been unable to find the right hardware to terminate the top rail at the 1.75" post. Everything that I've found has been for a 2 3/8" terminating post.

Can I just cut off the horizontal pipe, put something over the end, and leave it in the existing cap? Is there another way to terminate the top rail?

[Edit] new picture to show the location of the terminator post that the gate will be hung from.
[image: New gate setting against existing fence]

Comment: Are you certain that little post can support a gate?  Even more so without the adjoining posts supporting it?  You might want to cut the top rail, pull up the little post and pour your own 2 3/8" post into a solid fitting.

Comment: 2-3/8" posts are usually used at the corners or for gates.  Hence they make the proper top caps for those uses.  The 1-3/4" post you have in your picture is for a middle of the run.

Comment: I'm putting in a 2 3/8" post to hang the gate from on the other side of the gate.

Comment: I updated the picture in the post to show where the terminator post will go that the gate will be hung from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you used a *rail end* fitting and cut the connecting lug off. File it smooth and your done...

[image]

Comment: And then glue the cap on to the top rail? I'll look at that tomorrow.

Comment: Glue it to the top of your small diameter "latch post".

Comment: I ended up just sticking the end rail cap through the top cap, and called it good. It's not sticking out, and it's not coming loose. Thanks!